# Regex RedirectMatch to Remove Question Mark and Query String Parameter

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have a Joomla site that no longer users a calendar component, and I need to redirect all the old URLs back to the homepage.  The URL's look like this...

```
http://www.example.com/week/?date=2006-03-05&print=1&tmpl=component
http://www.example.com/week/?date=2010-09-12
http://www.example.com/week/?date=2007-04-01&print=1&tmpl=component
```

I've tried writing a RedirectMatch in the .htaccess file to remove everything after the domain, but I am only able to remove week/ from the URL, the question mark and parameters remain. This presents issues with certain parameters which remove the template, modules or format the page for printing.

Can anyone suggest a solution?  Here is what I've tried so far...

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/week/\?.* http://www.example.com
RedirectMatch 301 ^/week/\?(.*) http://www.example.com
RedirectMatch 301 ^/week/\?+.+ http://www.example.com
RedirectMatch 301 ^/week/\?+(.*) http://www.example.com
```

And the same rules without the opening caret...

```
RedirectMatch 301 /week/\?.* http://www.example.com
RedirectMatch 301 /week/\?(.*) http://www.example.com
RedirectMatch 301 /week/\?+.+ http://www.example.com
RedirectMatch 301 /week/\?+(.*) http://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

For url:

```
http://example.com/week/?date=2010-09-12
```

Could you try this rule:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^.*week/?$ www.example.com [R]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  But for some reason, neither of those trigger a match and no redirect is created. I get a Dynamic Joomla 404 Error page.

Comment: Thats odd. Does your week sub directory have a .htaccess file of its own?

Comment: Not sure. The folder structure looks like this: home/username/domain.com

There is only one .htaccess file in /domain.com/, and there is not an .htaccess file in either home/ or home/username/

Comment: Hmm just to clarify: is all .../week/... links invalid? I'm not too familiar with Joomla but the folder i thought of was `http://www.example.com/week/` . If that path exists, is there a .htaccess file there?

Comment: No, that folder does not physically exist on the server. It never did, the Joomla component simply added /week/ to the URL to make it search engine friendly. So the only htaccess file is located in the domains folder at home/username/domain.com

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately that did not work either. It's removing the /week/ part, but leaving in the query parameter. I think Joomla is appending the query parameter after the rule is run. I created another rewrite rule to remove all question marks in URLs and it through the server into a loop.

Comment: Yeah,the thing is, parameters is removed by default. There is a flag that explicitly says parameters should be saved.